# Textfield with Autofocus and MenuItem

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using React & Material-ui v3

I want to open a Dialog with a textField auto-focused
The dialog is open with a Menu / MenuItem from Material-UI
Somehow the autoFocus seems to work for a very short moment with the MenuItem collapsing.

Here is a [simple codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o7zm868o8z)

Does anyone have an idea about how to resolve my issue?
Using ref?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after messing with your sandbox a bit i think i found the problem, when you open you reset the focus, try modifying this functions like this:

```
  openDialog = () => {
    this.setState({
      isDialogOpen: true,
      anchorEl: this.state.anchorEl
    });
  };
```

Comment: It's a good solution and working great on the sanbox. Unfortunately, it's not usable for my project since Menu & Dialog are on 2 different components, with separated state.
But I just resolved it by using react-focus-lock !

Thanks for your help!